# Ember Simple Auth when all pages requires authorization

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have website that requires authorization on all its pages. To achieve that there is server that response based on cookie. If there is cookie send ember app, login site otherwise. This allows to facebook like behavior. I am using [ember-simple-auth](http://ember-simple-auth.com/) addon to help with authorization.

Since user is never inside app without being successfully authorized, one should be able to save ember-data record object into session. This works nice for one tab but breaks horrible with multiple tabs. Is there way how to have ember-data objects in session and yet support multiple browser tabs?

**Edit:**

I maybe found workaround, save index into session and use `peekRecord` in computed property.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If user can't see an app without being authorized, than you don't need ember-simple auth at all. Also, cookie-based authorization can work perfectly without ember-simple-auth.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was so focused to fix incompatibilities with simple-auth that I didn't realized I don't need it in first place. I was wondering why there is no mention of this use-case anywhere, well that explains that..